# Why won't my subtitles and captions show up using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am currently making some plots showing the most common industries in various towns on Long Island, NY. The plot itself looks pretty much exactly how I want except I can't seem to get the subtitle or caption I want into the final plot. Here is the code I am using:

```
    hemp_occ_plot <- ggplot(aes(x = occ_cat, y = count), data = occ_hempstead)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill =c("#84D6B8", "#B8574D", "#B03B70", "#5AA197", "#21262A", "#724B65", "#772684", "#052A7F",  "#D08F70", "#A3B2D8", "#4B1F28", "#CEC67E", "#FE8EA4"))+
  ggtitle(label = "Most Common Industries Among Hemsptead Workers", subtitle = "Showing 408,460 Civilian Workers")+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "Workers per Industry", 
       caption = "Source: ACS, 2019")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", face = "bold", size = (15), hjust = -1, vjust = 0),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (12), hjust = -1, vjust = 0),
        axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (12), vjust = 1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (10)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (12)))+
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("Agriculture_etal","Construction","Manufacturing","Wholesale_Trade","Retail_Trade","Transportation_Utilities","Information","Finance_Insurance_Realty","Professional","Eds_and_Meds","Entertainment_Hospitality","Other","Public_Administration"),
                   labels = c("Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing, Hunting, and Mining",
                              "Construction",
                              "Manufacturing",
                              "Wholesale Trade",
                              "Retail Trade",
                              "Transportation, Warehousing, and Utilities",
                              "Information",
                              "Finance, Insurance, Real Estate, Rental  and Leasing",
                              "Professional, Scientific, and Waste Management",
                              "Education, Health Care, and Social  Assistance",
                              "Arts, Entertainment, and Hospitality",
                              "Other Services, Except Public Administration",
                              "Public Administration"))+
  coord_flip()
```

[Here is what the plot looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4fKK.png)

Comment: `hjust = -1` in your `theme` call for `plot.subtitle` puts the subtitle outside the plot window.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the hjust settings in your `theme(plot.title, plot.subtitle)` call. From the Datanovia webpage: [https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-title-subtitle-and-caption/#:~:text=The%20default%20ggplot%20title%20alignment,element_text(hjust%20%3D%200.5)](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-title-subtitle-and-caption/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20ggplot%20title%20alignment,element_text(hjust%20%3D%200.5)))%20.

```
    hjust and vjust: number in [0, 1], for horizontal and vertical adjustment of titles, respectively.
    hjust = 0.5: Center the plot titles.
    hjust = 1: Place the plot title on the right
    hjust = 0: Place the plot title on the left
```

It's not recommended to use hjust or vjust values outside [0,1].